# How do I hide 'No Internet Connection' in fullscreen Chrome (on airplane wifi)?

Tags: wi-fi, chrome-for-android, airplane-mode

I've started using my phone to watch movies via the in-flight wifi when flying, however Chrome stubbornly reports 'No Internet Connection', which appears as a fairly sizeable and annoying banner on the top when watching a movie fullscreen.  Note: In this case there really is no outside internet connection, I just want to be able to dismiss the warning.

Is there any way to suppress this message?

Or any suggestions on an alternate browser to download+use that might not have this issue?  I've found so far that Firefox browser doesn't work at all for Southwest's in-flght pages.

Comment: I didn't find any flags at chrome://flags related to your requirement. But if you ask for browsers there are too many but most of them are chrome based like Opera, Brave, Edge etc. So give them a try. One which is use personally - Via Browser. Some more - Samsung Browser, Kiwi, DuckDuckGo and soooo onnnn...